# In Perl, how to speed up regex to modify a really big string?

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a string which comprised of 300 million bases;

```
$str = "ATCGTAGCTAGXCTAGCTAGCTGATXXXXATCGTAGCTAGCTGXTGCTAGCXXXXA...A";
```

I want to replace characters that are not [ATGC] in the string to something else, let's say to "A", meanwhile get the positions of characters that have be replaced;

I tried this:

```
while ($str=~/[^ATGC]/ig)
{
  $pos = pos($str);
  substr($str, $pos-1,1) = "A";
}
```

but the speed is not good.

Does anyone know better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to replace the "X" characters in your input string, transliteration is the way to go and will improve your speed dramatically.

Logging the positions of the substituted characters is a bit of an added wrinkle.  I'd suggest something like the following:

```
my $huge_string = "GATTACAXX.......";
my $length = length($huge_string);
my $i = 0;

my $output_string;
my @x_positions;

while ($i < $length) {
    my $curr_char = substr($huge_string, $i, 1);
    if ($curr_char eq "X") {
        push (@x_positions, $i);
        $output_string .= "A"; # or G, C, T, etc.
    } else {
        $output_string .= $curr_char;
    }
    $i++;
}

# do something with $output_string and @x_positions...
```

I ran this on a test string of >1,000,000 characters and it was finished in less than a second, vs. about 3 minutes runtime for the original code snippet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. This actually works well. I was trapped in the idea of regex.

Answer (score 6):

Regexes can also substitute as well as match.

```
$str =~ s/X/A/g;
```

If you're only doing a single character, you can even use the `tr` operator.

```
$str =~ tr/X/A/g;
```

which may even be faster.

Answer (score 5):

You can perform the replacement with regex directly using [search and replace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace):

```
$str =~ s/X/A/ig;
```

Comment: Thanks, FJ. I also want to track the positions of chars that have been replaced.

Comment: @ShichenWang then please ask a question about the thing you're actually trying to do :)

Comment: Things get more complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.14;

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my @l = qw(A T G C X);
my $BAR;
$BAR .= $l[rand(@l)] for 1..10000;

cmpthese(-1, {
    substr          => sub { my $str = $BAR; 
                         while ($str=~/X/ig) {
                             my $pos = pos($str);
                             substr($str, $pos-1,1) = "A";
                         } return $str; },
    substitution    => sub { my $str = $BAR; $str =~ s/X/A/ig;  return $str; },
    transliteration => sub { my $str = $BAR; $str =~ tr/xX/aA/; return $str; }});
```

**Results:**

```
                   Rate          substr    substitution transliteration
substr           55.1/s              --            -98%           -100%
substitution     2496/s           4433%              --            -93%
transliteration 35134/s          63719%           1308%              --
```

As we can see by the results, for this particular string and regex, the substr method is very slow indeed at a rate of 55 per second. Using a substitution is about 45 times faster, but this is dwarfed by the transliteration which is 600 times faster.

So, it would seem that transliteration is the fastest in this case. It makes sense, since it is by far the most simple of the subs.

Comment: In my eyes, you made the `substr` routine unneccesarily complex by using a regex to match a single character. I haven't tested this, but how about a `for` loop and `eq` to compare `substr($str, $i, 1)`s?

Comment: @mpe I haven't made the routine complex, I copied it from the question. You mean something like going through every character, checking if it is "X", and then replacing it? Yeah, you could try that. That would be a simple way to save the positions of the matches too. Try it out and add it as an answer.

Comment: @mpe Well, I tried it out, and it performs better than the original substr, but not as well as substitution. You still need to do two `substr` calls, one to check and one to assign.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply replacing one character by another (**not** character-by-string or string-by-string!!!), transliteration is faster: `$str =~ tr/X/A/;`
If you need complex regex patterns, consider using [re::engine::RE2](https://metacpan.org/module/re%3a%3aengine%3a%3aRE2), a Perl binding for [Google RE2 engine](http://code.google.com/p/re2/). Note that is is only faster for *complex* regex.